# How to group by multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, crosstab

I need to group my data by three columns - gender, year and employment status.

Here is my data:

```
ID <- c(1000, 1000, 1000, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002)
Gender <- as.factor(c("M","M","M","M","M","M","M","M","F","F","F","F","F"))
Employment_status <- as.factor(c("Other","Other","Other","Employed","Employed","Employed","Employed","Employed","Employed","Employed","Employed","Employed","Unemployed"))
Year <- c(2016, 2017, 2018, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020)

my_data <- data.frame(ID, Gender, Employment_status, Year, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I wish that my end result would entail a data table about the employment rate by gender and by year. How could I achieve this in R?

Expected output would be something like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: could you include the expected output?

Comment: I added the expected output! This could be in a different form, but these are the percentages I am looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```
ftable(prop.table(table(my_data[-1]), c(1, 3)), col.vars = c("Gender", "Employment_status"))


     Gender                   F                         M                 
     Employment_status Employed Other Unemployed Employed Other Unemployed
Year                                                                      
2016                        1.0   0.0        0.0      0.5   0.5        0.0
2017                        1.0   0.0        0.0      0.5   0.5        0.0
2018                        1.0   0.0        0.0      0.5   0.5        0.0
2019                        1.0   0.0        0.0      1.0   0.0        0.0
2020                        0.0   0.0        1.0      1.0   0.0        0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this roughly what you are going for?

```
library(dplyr)


my_data %>% 
  group_by(Gender, Year) %>% 
  count(Employment_status) %>% 
  summarise(sum(n)) %>% 
  arrange(Year)
```

Output:

```
   Gender  Year `sum(n)`
   <fct>  <dbl>    <int>
 1 F       2016        1
 2 M       2016        2
 3 F       2017        1
 4 M       2017        2
 5 F       2018        1
 6 M       2018        2
 7 F       2019        1
 8 M       2019        1
 9 F       2020        1
10 M       2020        1
```

Comment: If the question is unclear, do not answer it, flag it for closure.